# Code which was built with g++7, crashes with access to unaligned memory

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, g++, memory-alignment

It is strange behaviour when I try to run program, which was built with g++ and optimization -O2.
Using:

- g++-7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
- kernel 4.15.0-36-generic

I have structure with two members:

```
struct A {                                   
    uint8_t m8;                              
    Int128 m128;                                          
};
```

Where `Int128` is:

```
// #pragma pack(push, 1)               
struct Base128 {
    __int128_t v{0};        
};              
// #pragma pack(pop)  

#pragma pack(push, 1)               
struct Int128: Base128 {            
    Int128();                       
};                                   
#pragma pack(pop)
```

`Base128` is explicitly non-packed, but `Int128` is packed with alignment `1`
Be noticed that `Base128` has explicit member initialization and `Int128` has manually-defined constructor with empty body at another translation unit (for avoiding inlining).

When I change `Base128` packing to be same as `Int128`, program doesn't crash.

It seems that compiler generates invalid instruction: `MOVAPS` instead of `MOVUPS` for accessing to `__int128_t` member in constructor:

```
00000000000006b0 <_ZN6Int128C1Ev>:
 6b0:    66 0f ef c0              pxor   %xmm0,%xmm0
 6b4:    55                       push   %rbp
 6b5:    48 89 e5                 mov    %rsp,%rbp
 6b8:    0f 29 07                 movaps %xmm0,(%rdi)
 6bb:    5d                       pop    %rbp
 6bc:    c3                       retq   
 6bd:    0f 1f 00                 nopl   (%rax)
```

Vice versa:

```
00000000000006b0 <_ZN6Int128C1Ev>:
 6b0:    66 0f ef c0              pxor   %xmm0,%xmm0
 6b4:    55                       push   %rbp
 6b5:    48 89 e5                 mov    %rsp,%rbp
 6b8:    0f 11 07                 movups %xmm0,(%rdi)
 6bb:    5d                       pop    %rbp
 6bc:    c3                       retq   
 6bd:    0f 1f 00                 nopl   (%rax)
```

Do you have any idea: what I do wrong?

Source code:

test.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

//#pragma pack(push, 1) // it fixes problem
struct Base128 {
    __int128_t v{0};
};
//#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct Int128: Base128 {
    Int128();
}; 
#pragma pack(pop)

struct A {
    uint8_t m8; 
    //Int128 __attribute__((aligned(16))) m128; // it fixes problem
    Int128 m128;    
};
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

// Int128::Int128() : Base128{0} {} // Fixes (why ?!)
Int128::Int128() {}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
int main() {
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Building and running:

```
g++-7 --save-temps -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -O2 -g main.cpp test.cpp && ./a.out
```

[Source code on gitlab is here](https://gitlab.com/prog-devel/test-gcc-unaligned-128). It can be built and run as listed below:

```
./build.sh # build and run (crashes)
./build.sh [1..5] # where 1..5 -- different fixes
```

Comment: I didn't check the details, but `#pragma pack(push, 1)` looks suspicious. And please provide a [mcve] (emphasis on minimal) here in the question, not via an external link.

Comment: Can you please edit out the `#ifdef`s in your code so that we only see the version of the test that is failing please? This is hard to follow as-is.

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed your notes

Comment: My gut tells me that this is a compiler bug, but I gotta say that having an explicitely unaligned struct **inheriting** from an aligned struct is a bit of a recipe for disaster, and I wouldn't be surprised if there isn't some fundamentally irreconcilable conflict here with how casts would be performed  between pointers of the two types. Maybe the bug is that compilation was successful in the first place...

Comment: Yes, I expect that compiler will warn me, at least

Comment: Yeah... Consider the following: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ZV_Ya1. `foo()` is clearly impleneted how it should be, but `bar()` leads to disaster in the exact same way you are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you, @Frank. Looks like compiler don't know that object of base class may be unaligned in memory when calling its constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) of `alignas`, which as far as I can tell is equivalent to gcc's packing attribute:

> If the strictest (largest) alignas on a declaration is weaker than the alignment it would have without any alignas specifiers (that is, weaker than its natural alignment or weaker than alignas on another declaration of the same object or type), the program is ill-formed:

```
struct alignas(8) S {};
struct alignas(1) U { S s; }; // error: alignment of U would have been 8 without alignas(1)
```

This example is effectively the exact same thing as yours (treating a class' parent as its first member).

So we can definitely say that your program is ill-formed, thus invoking **Undefined Behavior**. Most of your workarounds can be dismissed as basically just "luck". No need for an explanation as to why they work.

Interestingly, when swapping in the standard `alignas()` in your code, gcc still does not complain, but clang starts correctly reporting the error: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EEErXg

**Edit:** For reference on the equivalence between `alignas()` and gcc's packing:

GCC says it's a straight port of the MSVC feature: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

And Microsoft says that `alignas()` is the same thing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx

Comment: Interesting that when making Base128 alignas(1) clang causes the same error. It seems that alignas can't be declared with the value less than size of 128_t (16). But when using __attribute__((packed)) it is all ok